# firefox and IE returning attributes in different order than chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm getting different values in different browsers as the attributes list is in different order in different browsers. Is there any way to get the value of particular atribute??

```
$(e.target).siblings()[index+2].attributes[2].value
```

Answer (score 3):

You should never rely on order of an array especially if the source of the array isn't your code. The fix is simple. Just use the property name.

For example if you wanted `class` attribute, you'd do:

```
var key = "class";
var value = $(e.target).siblings()[index+2][prop]; // bracket notation
```

Comment: if my sibbling is <span class=" " data-id ="" data-value=""></span>. If I use $(e.target).siblings()[index+2][data-id]; i'm getting data is not defined error

Comment: @Kumar not `[data-id]`,  `["data-id"]`

Answer (score 1):

Since your are using jQuery already, you could use that object as well:

```
$(e.target).siblings().eq(0).attr("data-id");
```

or (better if using the data I would think)

```
$(e.target).siblings().eq(0).data("id");
```

or some other attribute: (like the cool one)

```
$(e.target).siblings().eq(0).attr("cool");
```

NOTE: `$(e.target).siblings()` returns the siblings of the target element - potentially more than one element.  Thus the `.eq(n)` selects the nth element of that, 0 being the first.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and IE try to create a list in source code order, but the order is off. Check compatibility table for attributes array in [quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t120). Do yourself a favor and don't use the indexed attributes array. Use getAttribute() instead.